# Mac Safari (12 / 13) would automatically lose his voice after 5-10 mins

Tags: safari, video-streaming, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am experiencing a unique issue where a user on Safari would automatically lose its voice after 5-10 mins.
I am using Agora SDK NG  and see that it is 1 of known safari bugs (https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/browser_support#safari).
However,  this is not rare and keep occurring consistently.  This doesn't ever happen for chrome users.
Is it something missing in Safari or limitation by Agora?

If it is webrtc's limitation  on safari then would other platforms like Jitsi should also have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agora's Web SDK (current and NG) are based on WebRTC and leverage browsers' support for WebRTC in order to function without needing any specialized plugins.

While Safari does support WebRTC functionality, it offers minimal feature support when compared to Chrome and Firefox browsers. If you are seeing different behavior in Safari as compared to Chrome/Firefox when using the same code, then it's most likely caused by a limitation within Safari with respect to WebRTC support.

Comment: Thanks @hermes.

What I am more intrigued about is that why isn't this issue in meet or Skype.